# Importing a dynamic MaterialUI theme object from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone help me understand the correct syntax for allowing a dynamic theme object to be imported from a separate file?

I am trying to get the system theme from a media query and then set the theme dynamically.

This works fine if I leave everything all in the main App function like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/theme-builder-working-all-in-one?file=index.js

But I want to have it broken up into different files for organization in the example below but my attempt is broken, I get the error: `themeProvider_js_1.default is not a function`

broken example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/theme-builder-broken?file=index.js

This is a second try of refactoring, no errors, I can see the ThemeObject existing in the console log but the system theme isn't being applied:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/theme-builder-broken-btyufg?file=index.js

Code for the future:
working code, but I want to refactor this so the theme and media query objects are outside of the App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

function App() {

  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme)');

  const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline/>
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

broken refactor attempt:

App component

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import themeBuilder from './themeProvider.js'

function App() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeBuilder()}>
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

themeBuilder

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

function themeBuilder() {

const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme)');

const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  return theme
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `export default` in `themeProvider.js`

```
export default function themeBuilder() {

const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme)');

const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  return theme
}
```

Comment: That fixed the error but it's not applying the correct color theme as seen here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/theme-builder-broken-qdw4ca?file=themeProvider.js Any ideas? I can see it outputting different boolean values..

Comment: `<CssBaseline/>` is missing

Comment: Ah damn it :). Thank you!

Comment: Also if you want to allow user change `darkMode`  programmatically you'd have to change approach completely as toggle button should store initial stare (`prefersDarkMode` vs entry in persistence) and every change should be saved somewhere ( ie. `localstorage` )

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, I am working my way towards that architecture. Any ideas as to why I am unable to use these Stackblitz examples in my local code? I am getting this error that the mediaQuery function needs to be in a react component:  ```Line 7:25:  React Hook "useMediaQuery" is called in function "themeBuilder" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function``` I am using the exact same themeBuilder from the example..

Comment: If I capitalize the function name to make it a React function, it seems to work fine. Strange..